# Does "container" have minimal OS of its own where Apps run?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I am learning Docker and came across the term `container`; as I understood it is the `container` where the apps run, for example, we can run `httpd` daemon.

From the various online materials which i read, it appears that the `container` have the minimal OS of its own, and other "part" it shares with host OS.

Is this understanding correct?

If this is correct, then if I consider a case in which a container have `Windows OS`, and the host OS is `CentOS`, then how would `Windows OS` share the `CentOS` kernel?

Can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of docker container is that it's like portable workspace so you can build it from image over and over again in different os

And this is working because containerls are preconfigured virtual machine

Hope that answer you question

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers indeed share the same `kernel` with the host and if your apps have some interactions or change the kernel, then your container/image will not be so portable as you might think. You will run into some issues when running on different kernel based OSs.

***Base Image***: Look into [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch/) if you want to know more about the smallest image/directives that you can build your images on top of it. I would not say that the containers have OS, but they have a single binary and you build and apply your layers on top of that.

***Daemon***: You can deamonize your app, but there are also a one-time running containers and they terminate after they go through all the directives that you specified.